# SSRS Gantt Chart - Change to date format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, date-format, gantt-chart

As per attached image, i have dates running along the X axis that starts on the 1st Jan 2012 and then increases monthly.

My problem is the format is displaying the month/day/year and I want day/month/year.

I have looked at Horizontal Axis Properties and under 'Number' but Date does not seem to be there.

Does anyone have any suggestions on changing the format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'Custom' and supply a date formatting string such as dd/MM/yyyy will give 01/09/2010 for example.